# List of peole who can see your online status in Google Talk

Tags: google-talk

I removed some friends from my friend list of my Google Talk, I did not block them. So they see my online status and can send instant message to me.

How can I see a list of the people that can see me online on their Google talk?

Comment: How many contacts do you have on your chat list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can see such a list anywhere.

However, you can always go invisible.

Apparently(I've not tested it) you can make certain contacts to not see your actual online status. If contacts are few on your chat list then: (a dig up from Google forums):

[Remove a contact from Gmail chat list without blocking or deleting the contact](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/talk/ZAbvaKzBtEA)

Post from user `coloradan`, it's not straight forward as it sounds.